# Check time to make sure I don't go over max duration set while in a loop? (Python)

Tags: python, time

What function of the time module can I use to get the time and do math on it?

```
MAX_DURATION = 60

startTime = get the time
while(True):
    wait random seconds
    curTime = get the time
    if curTime - startTime > MAX_DURATION:
        break
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import time

time.time()
```

This should fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want `datetime` and especially `timedelta`: http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

For example:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import random

MAX_DURATION = timedelta(seconds=60)
start = datetime.now()
while 1:
    time.sleep(random.random())
    now = datetime.now()
    if now - start > MAX_DURATION:
        break
```

(of course, in this very simple case it might be better to simply use `time.time()` (which returns a [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), then compare that with a number of seconds (ex, `time.time() - start > MAX_SECONDS`)… But this is how you'd do it in a “fully general” way)